# sql stored procedure to search for keyword in a table column

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table called testimonials. I need to store a database procedure that searches the 'contents' columns for the keyword and displays the matching rows. I using sql plus.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Search_Testimonials
  (@WRDSRCH VARCHAR2)
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Testimonials
    where content like concat('%',WRDSRCH,'%');
  END;
  /
```

I keep getting Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Comment: Parameter don't use `@` in Oracle. And you need something to store the result of your query in.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code (you cannot use TSQL code without adapting it):

- parameter names don't use @ in Oracle (as mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name)
- you need something to store the result in (again, as mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name)
- you cannot call CONCAT with 3 arguments; to concatenate strings, you can use the `||` operator

A possible implementation for Oracle (using a ref cursor for the search results) would be

```
CREATE TABLE testimonials
(pk NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 content VARCHAR2(100));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Search_Testimonials(WRDSRCH VARCHAR2,
                                                v_cur   IN OUT sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur FOR
    SELECT *
      FROM Testimonials
     WHERE content LIKE '%' || WRDSRCH || '%';
END;
```

Usage (from SQL/Plus):

```
var x refcursor;
begin 
  search_testimonials('hello', :x); 
end;
/
print x;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name, '@' is not used while using variables.
Also the concat function is not appropriate in your case.
The corrected version of your procedure is

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE Search_Testimonials (WRDSRCH in VARCHAR2,o_cursor out sys_refcursor)
  is
  BEGIN
   OPEN o_cursor FOR 
    SELECT * FROM Testimonials
   where content LIKE '%' || WRDSRCH || '%';
  END;
```

if you are running from sqlplus or sql developer use the following command to execute.

```
var rc refcursor
exec Search_Testimonials ('A',:rc);
print rc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes suggested by a_horse_with_no_name, as per my personal opinion, are two biggest changes we have to make in our codes when we migrate from SQL Server to Oracle.

I would suggest you create a function, instead of a procedure, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Search_Testimonials
(WRDSRCH VARCHAR2)
RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
    ret_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN ret_cur FOR
    SELECT *
      FROM Testimonials
     WHERE content like '%'||WRDSRCH||'%';

    RETURN ret_cur;
END;
/
```

The advantage of using such a function is that you can simply run a query like the following and get the result in Toad or SQL Developer:

```
SELECT Search_Testimonials ('some_text')
  FROM dual;
```

The result will contain just one cell saying `(CURSOR)` but double-clicking on that will give you the entire result set.